# Fn and ln in JavaClass Person

Tags: java, user-interface, ibm-mobilefirst

[image]

I don't know how to fix the error in the code.

Fn and ln in JavaClass Person

Comment: Questions here cannot depend on screenshots of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to write FN in the brackets.

```
 Person p = new Person("Ali", "Ahmadi");
```

Maybe, you should look for some code samples. It's really helpful - also to learn some best-practices. [Maybe codesamples like this.](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/31elementary/Person.java.html)

Btw: Code Samples as image is...
Providing the sample code with the editors "code sample" function would be nice.